# Failed top open IndexedDB on Firefox OS

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, firefox-os

I've created a FirefoxOS app that uses INdexedDb for storage and I'v used  [IDBWrapper](https://github.com/jensarps/IDBWrapper) for IndexedDB operations. I have tested the app on Chrome and Firefox browsers and it works perfectly. But as soon as i run the app on the Simulator the app does not store values in the IndexedDB.

When i try to save something it throws an error stating that 'this.db' is null.

**The code for Database Creation**

```
var dbOptions = {
        storeName: 'geoDiary',
        storePrefix: 'k2v-software-',
        dbVersion: 1,
        keyPath: 'ID',
        autoIncrement: true,
        indexes: [
            { name: 'Lat', keyPath: 'Lat', unique: false, multiEntry: false },
            { name: 'Lon', keyPath: 'Lon', unique: false, multiEntry: false },
            { name: 'Title', keyPath: 'Title', unique: false, multiEntry: false },
            { name: 'Description', keyPath: 'Description', unique: false, multiEntry: false },
            { name: 'Timestamp', keyPath: 'Timestamp', unique: false, multiEntry: false }
        ],
        onError: function(error) {
            $log.error(error);
        }
    };

    // create instance of datastore
    var idbDataStore = new IDBStore(dbOptions);
```

**function where the save operation is called.**

```
$scope.saveToDB = function() {
        //var ID = new Date().getTime();
        var title = $scope.saveData.title;
        var description = $scope.saveData.description;
        var latitude = $scope.currentPosition.coords.latitude.toFixed(5);
        var longitude = $scope.currentPosition.coords.longitude.toFixed(5);
        var currentdate = new Date();
        var timestamp = currentdate.getDate() + "/"
            + (currentdate.getMonth()+1)  + "/"
            + currentdate.getFullYear() + " @ "
            + currentdate.getHours() + ":"
            + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":"
            + currentdate.getSeconds();


        var newRecord = {
            //ID: ID,
            Lat: latitude,
            Lon: longitude,
            Title: title,
            Description: description,
            Timestamp: timestamp
        };

        idbDataStore.put(newRecord, function () {
            // success callback
            //ID = null;
            title = null;
            description = null;
            latitude = null;
            longitude = null;
            currentdate = null;
            timestamp = null;
        }, callbackError);
    };
```

The error occurs on the idbstore.js which is the library i got for IDBWrapper from Github. in that file in line is where the error originates, the line of code is here.

```
var putTransaction = this.db.transaction([this.storeName], this.consts.READ_WRITE);
```

the error is `this.db` is null. I can't set a breakpoint and step through the code to figure out where the problem is exactly since WebIDE does not show the idbstore.js file. Can some one please help me figure out what is going on. Thanks in advance.